# attempting to create 100 objects in an array using loops in java

Tags: java

i'm attempting to create a map for a jrpg in java i'm working on as a learning project. I've made a 10x10 array on terrain objects called map, and created a terrain object, independent of the array, as a test. next i attempt to create a terrain object for each iteration of the map 2d array. here i get the error 
"terrain cannot be resolved to a variable"
i have played around with moving a few lines, and done 30 or more minutes of google searches looking for a solution. any help or hints would be very much appreciated.

```
terrain[ ][ ] map = new terrain[10][10];

terrain T1   =  new terrain();


public void mapp(){

    int a = RPGmain.test.game.map.length;
    int c=0;
    int d=0;
    while (c <= a){
        int b = RPGmain.test.game.map[c].length;
        while(d <= b){
            terrain map[c][d]= new terrain();  // <------ the first terrain in this line is where i get the error

            d++;
        }
        d=0;
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `terrain map[c][d]` --> `map[c][d]`.

Comment: You have a space between `terrain` and `map`. I'm not sure what you're even trying to do there. Did you mean to just put `map[c][d]= new terrain();`?

Comment: The name of the class should start with a capital letter. It's better to call class `Terrain` rather than `terrain`

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a field or a variable you need to specify its type:

```
int d=0;
```

when you are assigning to already defined variable, you just need the name of that variable and new value:

```
d=0;
```

It's the same with arrays. You already declared map as:

```
terrain[ ][ ] map = new terrain[10][10];
```

you don't need to specify the type when assigning:

```
map[c][d]= new terrain();
```

Comment: Thanks alot! that is exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

You just need:

```
map[c][d]= new terrain();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using a `for` loop when you know how many iterations you're going to need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    map[i][j] = new Terrain(); 
  }
}
```

Note also that, by convention, the names of classes begin with a capital letter. The compiler won't complain if you disregard this, but you'll thank yourself for it when you come to debug your code in future.

Comment: Thanks for the info,  I will do that!